# it doesnt go the JS function and goes straightly to process.php idk why

Tags: javascript, php, function, validation

```
<script>
function hi(){
alert("hi"); //assuming this is the validation

}
 </script>

 <form action="process/register.php" method="POST" onSubmit="hi()"  name="register-form">

<button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Register</button>
</script.
```

IDK why it immediately goes straight to process without going through the JS function hi();

I am sure my codes are right. Need help.

Comment: It does go through the javascript function, but it also loads a new page, which is why you don't see the alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to stop submitting to the new page, you could do alot of things, two examples:

```
onsubmit="hi(); return false;" <!--Makes sure the form doesn't submit after calling your function-->
```

or

```
onsubmit="hi(event);" <!--Pass the event as parameter-->
```

And then in the `hi()` function

```
function hi(e) {
    alert("hi");
    e.preventDefault(); //stops event from posting form. this is why we sent the event as param.
    return false; //extra measure to make sure. (not required)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="process/register.php" method="POST" onSubmit="return hi()"  name="register-form">
```

keep in mind to return true or false in that function.